# How do I test if an ActiveRecord attribute is an Enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How would I test if an ActiveRecord attribute is an Enum? (as per Rails 4.1 enum declaration)

It's stored in the database and using the type method on columns_hash identifies the attribute as an integer.

Enum definition in model

```
enum status: [ :in_progress, :accepted, :approved, :declined, :closed, :cancelled, :submitted ]
```

To pull the type

```
irb(main):030:0> Application.columns_hash['status'].type
=> :integer
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Enum` adds a `defined_enums` class attribute to the model - a hash storing the defined enums:

```
MyModel.defined_enums
#=> {"status"=>{"in_progress"=>0, "accepted"=>1, "approved"=>2, "declined"=>3, "closed"=>4, "cancelled"=>5, "submitted"=>6}}
```

To test if an attribute is an enum you could use:

```
MyModel.defined_enums.has_key?('status')
#=> true
```

Unfortunately, `defined_enums` is not documented.

Comment: Brilliant! The attribute test is exactly what I needed too. Thank you.

Comment: any rails5 way for this?

Comment: @masciugo `defined_enums` still exits in Rails 5

Comment: oook that model name (Application) got me wrong ... tnx

Answer (score -1):

I kept on finding this answer when trying to figure out how to do this, but @stefan's method was giving me an `uninitialized constant PostsHelper::Application`

Found this also works:

```
Post.type_for_attribute(attribute).is_a
```

Possibly a bit cleaner, since you don't have to worry about `_prefix` and `_suffix`?